# SQL Server- Trouble using less than symbol in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Salary, Salary = (Case Employees.Salary
When salary < 40000 then 'Low Pay'
When salary < 70000 then 'Medium Pay'
Else 'High Pay'
End) as 'PayRange'
From Employees;
```

I am trying to make this case statement work but keep getting an incorrect syntax error on the < symbol. The data type of salary is numeric. What is my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're combining syntax.  You can remove `Employees.Salary`, and it will work.

Example that should work:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Salary,  (Case
When salary < 40000 then 'Low Pay'
When salary < 70000 then 'Medium Pay'
Else 'High Pay'
End) as 'PayRange'
From Employees;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is a link to see proper syntax for `CASE()` expressions.

Comment: You can only do the first (what you show.) The second option (`WHEN < 40000 ...`) will result in an error.

Comment: Good to know!  Will change my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Salary, 
    (Case 
        When Salary < 40000 then 'Low Pay'
        When Salary < 70000 then 'Medium Pay'
        Else 'High Pay'
    End) as 'PayRange'
From Employees;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two columns named Salary.  You need to either put "Salary =" in front of the column expression or use an "AS" at the end (not both, and you have conflicting names here).  Also, I don't think you need the first Employees.Salary after the Case.  Here is my suggestion:

```
Select FirstName
, LastName
, Salary
, PayRange = (Case 
        When Employees.Salary < 40000 then 'Low Pay'
        When Employees.Salary < 70000 then 'Medium Pay'
        Else 'High Pay'
        End)
From Employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even easier:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Salary, 
CASE WHEN salary < 40000 THEN 'Low Pay'
WHEN salary < 70000 THEN 'Medium Pay'
ELSE 'High Pay' END AS PayRange
FROM Employees;
```

This is MS SQL Server Syntax, might be a little different in other dialects.